# Oversize table with nested tabularx->minipage->tabular* has columns that are too narrow (Memoir)

Tags: tables, memoir, tabularx

I am trying to lay out a table heading that looks something like this:

```
      TITLE
---------------------      subtitle
  Name  Value             description
  Name  A value of         Name  Value 
        some length        Name  Value
```

Where *Name* and *Value* are arbitrary pairs of values (and value may be somewhat lengthy).

In my circumstances this layout is better set at a width greater than the background `\textwidth`. Unfortunately that *seems* to be the cause of an issue because in my layout the inner tables, containing Name/Value, are too narrow. The issue may be elsewhere, for example a problem with nesting tables - though the *memoir* package documentation specifically advises that nesting should be okay, save a workaround when `tabularx` environments are nested – not the case here.

Here is an example demonstrating the issue, with vertical lines added to the tabular environments for illustration:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \hspace{-3cm}%
  \begin{tabularx}{14cm}[t]{l |X|}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{9cm}%
      \centering
      {\Large Title}\\\medskip
      \RaggedRight
      \begin{tabular*}{9cm}{|r|X|}
      \toprule
      Name & Value \\
      Name & This is a long value that will wrap a couple of lines.\\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabular*}
    \end{minipage}} & %
    \begin{minipage}{6cm}
      \RaggedRight
      \begin{center}Subtitle\end{center}
      \textit{Description under the title}\\\bigskip
      \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{rl}
      Name & Some value\\
      Name & Value\\
      \end{tabular*}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

As you can see the effect is something like:

```
      TITLE
---------------------         subtitle
  Name | Value  |            description
  Name | A value|            Name  Value 
       | of some|            Name  Value
       |  length|
```

I seem to be able to get to something closer to the desired effect by giving all the tabular columns particular widths with `p{}`, though I have not yet worked it out and I expect there is a more elegant and dynamic solution than hard-coding everything (...but perhaps not).

I am using the *Memoir* package, and would enjoy thoughts on how to achieve the above using that package.

Comment: This isn't really related to `memoir` at all. I'm not quite sure as to what it is you want to do.

Comment: @daleif The memoir package has defined its own `tabular{,*,x}` commands and other peculiarities that may affect the outcome, so it seemed necessary to mention it.

Comment: They are more or less carbon copies of the code from the corresponding packages so I do not think there is anything related to memoir in the code above, using say, `article` plus `tabularx` would give you the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't really clear what you want to do (and you can't use `X` in a tabular*) however the markup here is a lot simpler and it might be close to the layout you want....

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \hspace{-3cm}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr(\textwidth+2cm)/2\relax}[t]{|l |X|}
      \toprule
       \multicolumn{2}{c}{\Large Title}\\
      \hline
      Name & Value \\
      Name & This is a long value that will wrap a couple of lines.\\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}\hfill
  \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr(\textwidth+2cm)/2\relax}[t]{|l |X|}
      \toprule
       \multicolumn{2}{c}{Subtitle}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{Description under the title}}\\
      \hline
      Name & Some value\\
      Name & Value\\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\noindent X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you David - that's exactly what I was looking for - a little illumination into how one might go about this sort of thing! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of hard-coding the widths:

```
 \hspace{-3cm}%
 \begin{tabularx}{18cm}[t]{p{10cm} p{7cm}}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
      \centering{\Large Title}\\\medskip
      \begin{tabular}{R{2cm} L{\linewidth - 3cm}}
      \toprule
      Name & Value \\
      Name 2 & This is Hello,world, how long %
               does this have to be? a long value %
               that will wrap a couple of lines.\\%
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    & %
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \noindent\begin{center}
      Subtitle\\
      \textit{Description under the title}
      \end{center}
      \begin{tabular*}{6cm}{R{2cm} L{4cm}}
      Name & Some value\\
      Name & Value\\
      \end{tabular*}
    \end{minipage}\\
  \end{tabularx}
```

As mentioned, it would be nice to solve this in a more dynamic and elegant way (i.e. if one were to change the width of one column the rest would adjust accordingly).

Comment: Couldn't you just use `\linewidth` as the width of the two minipages (untested)? Then at least their widths only depend on the `p{...}`.

Comment: @daleif Great tip; updating.